# Changing UITabBar tint color after splash screen

Tags: uitabbar, splash-screen, tint

I tried to read all the topics about uitabbar tint color but I couldn't find one that helped me.

I've no problem to change the tabbar tint color, but after launching the splash screen the tabbar color is for few instants white than it changes to the one I set on my application delegate in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

In the application delegate I first check the iOS version, I set the tabbar tint color, I call the splash screen that after 2.0 seconds dismisses itself presenting the uitabbarviewcontroller: the tint color is initially white then changes to the color I want.

Where is my error?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed changing the modalTransitionStyle, it was set UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve that caused the tabbar of the root view controller to be initially white, changed to UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.

Thanx